# Is it ok to attach a lot of event listeners?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, dom, addeventlistener

Assume I have some component, that represents some kind of *smart image* (IUKWIM :D).

```
export default class SmartImage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        visible: false
    }

    wrapper: HTMLDivElement

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll)
        this.handleScroll()
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll)
    }

    handleScroll = (event?: UIEvent) => {
        var box = this.wrapper.getBoundingClientRect()
        if (box.bottom < 0 || box.top > window.innerHeight) {
            if (this.state.visible)
                this.setState({ visible: false })
        } else {
            if (!this.state.visible)
                this.setState({ visible: true })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="c-image-wrapper" ref={r => this.wrapper = r}>
                {this.state.visible &&
                    <img src="someSource" className="u-fade-in" />
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Let's be absctract of details about heights of the wrapper when image is not rendered or something (assume that I already handled it, this is just an example of performance optimisation of the DOM).

So, the main target is, obviously, to make some kind of *performant list* of images. You probably know, that when there is a lot of images (especially if they are not optimized - large images, PNG with a lot of transparent pixels, etc.), then the page starts to lag.

So the idea is to let every rendered `SmartImage` to know, whether it is inside the viewport or not. For this I attach the listener for `window.onscroll` and dynamically detect, if the bounding box of the `SmartImage` is in viewport and, if necessary, toggle the visibility of the image. I can either use the conditional render or `{ display: "none" }` in the inline style, I know, but this is not the main question.

The main question is: if I will have a lot of these `SmartImage` components, will it be better to attach the only one event listener and watch for changes for the list of `SmartImage`s, or it is OK to attach a lot of single listeners for every `SmartImage` component? What is more performant?

AFAIK, `addEventListener` does not add an additional listener for every similar event, but creates list of handlers instead and executes it one-by-one. Is it true?

The question is more metaphysical, I suppose, but if someone had an experience with this kind of situations, please, it will be nice for me if you will give me some advices or explanations.

Appreciate any help or information!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This: _AFAIK, addEventListener does not add an additional listener for every similar event, but creates list of handlers instead and executes it one-by-one. Is it true?_ Event handlers are bound to DOM Nodes, so addEventListener will add additional listeners for similar events that are on different Nodes.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yeah, but if they are attached for the same node? (in this case - for the `Window` object)

Comment: Mulitple event listeners according to the spec: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#eventtarget-event-listener-list

Comment: `You probably know, that when there is a lot of images (especially if they are not optimized - large images, PNG with a lot of transparent pixels, etc.), then the DOM starts to lag.` This statement conflates download time with DOM parsing time. The DOM doesn't lag because you have many or large images.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, it *does*. Browser needs more time to rerender DOM with a lot of big images, so the scrolling performance is decreasing

Comment: @RandyCasburn `The event listener is appended to target’s event listener list and is not appended if it has the same type, callback, and capture.` Great, thank you :)

Comment: Of-course, metaphysically and all, adding exact duplicate listeners doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: @RandyCasburn what do you mean by *exact duplicate*? Each instance of `SmartImage` will have its own `wrapper` with it's own bounding box

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance Again, "rendering the DOM" isn't the DOM lagging. It's literally the repaints and reflows that are performed by the rendering engine, which is not part of the DOM parsing process. The DOM parser only sees `img` elements and incorporates those elements into the DOM tree - that's it. It doesn't matter how large the image is, the tree is built irrespective of that. This is why we have separate events for DOM Parsing complete (`DOMContentLoaded`) and resource downloading complete (`load`). I get your point, but you are not assigning the correct terminology to the process.

Comment: @ScottMarcus oh, okay, sorry, let's say not **DOM lags**, but **page lags** :) And thank you for clarifying! I have edited my question

Answer (score 4):

For most events like keyboard or mouse events adding one listener per item is typically not a big issue.

Events like `scroll` and `resize` however get triggered for every pixel change which makes them fire many times a second depending on rate of change

So if you had several hundred items all firing the event handlers many times a second in a fast move it can possibly bog down enough to affect user experience.

One way to improve performance is using techniques known as *"throttling"* or *"debouncing"* ( easily researched) that only run the code within the handler when it hasn't been called within the last `n` milliseconds

Using a higher order component that only adds one listener to monitor all of the like objects is likely a better approach and even just using one may require some throttling

Comment: (Another performance option - a lot more complicated, is to use virtual rendering: only render what's actually displayed on the screen.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And how about `{ passive: true }`? The Webkit developers said, that this will significantly increase the optimisation. Furthermore, the scroll and resize events don't being fired for every pixel, they are throttled by default

Comment: @MatthewHerbst React does this by default. Furthermore, he does this in the most performant way thanks to Fiber)

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance not familiar with *"throttled by default"* and it isn't hard to get buggy experiences using scroll event listeners. Perhaps browsers have  improved some throttling since I last really had to research doing this though. My past experience points to having to manually throttle them with setTimeout timers

Comment: @charlietfl for now, AFAIK, browsers (at least, Chrome) fire `scroll` event up to 10 times per second, so, if you have scrolled page for 1000px in 1 second, it won't be fired 1000 times, but about 10 (and you can easily check it). Mobile browsers, especially Safari, fire scroll event at the end of scroll animation :)

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance OK but along with that with a lot of dom searches and manipulation that causes repaints it can still cause issues that may require additional throttling. A higher order component is probably your best route

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance React does not do virtual rendering at all. You are thinking about the virtual DOM, which is not what I am talking about. Right now if you have 10,000 items in a list, and render them all via React, you will get 10,000+ DOM nodes on your page, even though just a few will be in view. Virtual rendering means filtering that list by what's in view so that you only put say, 100 items/nodes on the page, meaning you didn't have to create 9,900 other items.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst oh, probably, you are right. In this case, the main target of this question is actualy a part of virtual rendering. I did not understand you clearly, because I thought that you are talking about *updating only elements that are caught some changes*. Virtual rendering in web is pretty complex, and (IMHO) could not be achieved nowadays.

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance there are many libraries and tutorials that help do virtual rendering, especially for rendering lists. It's not all that complicated: get the measurements of the viewport, know how big each item in the list is, do some math...

Comment: @MatthewHerbst ...and for every little change realculate content height) I mean, the total and universal virtual rendering. Partial virtual rendering is really not *that complicated*, agree)

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance I think you should stop digging. The whole point of virtual rendering is to render partial content - the content that's in the viewport.